# Making Map Book with facing pages numbered near outside edge?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

I am creating a map book but do not want the page numbers for each map page to be on the same side (since its printed double sided), I need the page numbers to be placed on opposite sides.

I am using data driven pages.

How do I do this?

Comment: The page layout you are referring to is typically called 'facing pages' - that might help if you end up searching for additional information.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming the page numbers are pulled from the attribute table of the layer you are using to create the DDP and can therefore add a dynamic attribute.

[image: DDP Attribute]

If you have two text boxes one on each side for odd and even pages I think you should have two separate fields in the attribute table, one for odd the other even which would only display the text on the relevant pages as a blank field wouldn't display. Hopefully the image below makes that a bit clearer:

[image: DDP page numbering]

Comment: This is a good solution to maintain a single .mxd file.  ESRI's solution is to use [two separate documents](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s90000002p000000.htm).

Comment: How do you get to add ODd and Even pages?

Comment: @user42720 It would require modification to the attribute table of your DDP index grid feature. You would need to [add two fields](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Adding_fields/005s0000000v000000/), and then populate the values (in an edit session) as MAJ742 has shown in the images. If you have a lot of pages, s/he may have an established method adding the values to share, otherwise creative use of field calculator might save some time over manual editing.

Comment: I have 200 pages. any idea on how to automate it with the field calculator?

Comment: @user42720 How to calculate the page field values (odd/even) is now answered at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93618/how-to-use-field-calculator-to-assign-values-to-only-odd-or-even-page-fields-f