# Using Field Calculator to assign values to only Odd (or Even) page fields for Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, data-driven-pages

I am creating a map book but do not want the page numbers for each map page to be on the same side (since its printed double sided), I need the page numbers to be placed on opposite sides.

I am using data driven pages. On a previous post it was mentioned to use ODD and EVEN pages per [How to make Map Book with facing pages numbered near outside edge?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93280/map-book-with-opposing-numbered-pages).

However I have over 200 pages.

Is there a "creative" field calculator expression to use?

Comment: It'd be really helpful to see a screenshot of your attribute table. I assume you have a page number field that we could create an expression to grab the correct value.

Answer (score 5):

The **Field Calculator** configuration below can be used to set values on any odd numbers in your Odd pages field (and blanks in the other rows).

In order to simulate a Data Driven Pages index for test data, I used **[Create Fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000)** to create a polygon feature class in a file geodatabase, and then added text fields 4 characters in size called Odd and Even.

This index feature class has a numeric OID field and writes to an Odd field that is text.  I will leave you to work out how to do the Even field.  If you have a different numeric field specifying the page numbers (and order) just use that in place of OID.

The **modulo (%) operator** in Python, which is the crux of how to separate Odd from Even pages, is described **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python)**.

[image]

Parser: **Python**

**Pre-logic Script Code**:

```
def Reclass(oid):
  if oid % 2 == 1:
    return str(oid)
  else:
    return ""
```

**Odd =**

```
Reclass(!OID!)
```

Comment: what table has an OID that corresponds to the page number? That seems to be an unstated requirement for the solution to work.

Comment: Where does the pre-logic code pasted?

Comment: @Llaves Hopefully I have addressed your request for clarification in my revised Answer

Comment: @user42720 I have added a graphic which should make this clearer

Comment: PolyGeo: that did it. I'm aware that data-driven pages relies on a polygon layer to define the pages, I guess I'm not sure how in the case of something other than a regular grid the pages are ordered, presumably it's by the order of the OIDs, which let's your trick work, assuming they are consecutively numbered.

Comment: @Llaves There's no "trick" involved - DDP uses a **Sort Field** (which just needs to be numeric) that you configure when you [**enable DDP**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000002t000000) on a map - this defines the order of pages no matter what polygon features are used as your index - I just used OID in my test because it was a numeric field which happened to be in the attribute table of the first polygon feature class I grabbed to use as my DDP test index.

Comment: @PolygGeo: Again, thanks. I've only used DDP once, and that was a while ago, so I didn't remember there the user named a Sort Field.